# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' error

Tags: python

I am trying to print the associated value for each entered key separated by comma in a dictionary.

```
myDict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5....}
u_input = input("Enter a letter");
myList = [x.strip() for x in u_input.split(',')];

for ml in myDict:
    ml = myDict[myList];
    print(ml)
else:
    print("not found")
```

For ex. if the user enters, `a, r, b` print `1 not found 2`

I know the "not found" wouldn't work that way but It is just how I want it. I am getting:

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` any ideas?
I tried the list as a tuple but then I'm getting keyerror while the key exists.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19371472/625914

Comment: @behzad.nouri if I change it to tuple then I am getting a key error.

Comment: for ml in myDict: --> `for ml in myList: value = myDict.get(ml, "not found"); print value`

Comment: @Han-youngPark, I'm not searching in the list rather in the dictionary.

Comment: @Han-youngPark thanks it worked but when I enter multiple letters it only returns the first one. any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what do you want exactly. `for ml in myDict:` you assign again in loop. `ml = myDict[mylist]`. key must hashable type. but list can't be hashable

Comment: @Han-youngPark It works now but it doesn't return multiple values, only one value for first entered key.

Comment: OK! I see... You want multiple return!! I think it's not possible in dictionary. It must be searched in loop as I know.

Comment: @Han-youngPark, how do I do that tho?

Comment: If you want just one line print, then there is a few ways. Use `print  value,` instead `print value` in my code. or make empty list and store result in the list, and `print " ".join(list)`