# Adding key to my dict results in unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to code the BFS algorithm but I receive this error "unhashable type: 'list'" which I cannot handle. Can you help please?

```
mygraph = { "1": ["2", "4"], "2": ["3", "5"], "3": ["6"],
            "4": ["5","7"], "5": ["8"], "6": ["9"], "7": ["8"], "8": ["9"]}

level = {"1":None}
parent = {"1":None}
i = 1
frontier = ["1"]

while frontier:
    nex = []
    adj = []
    for u in frontier:
        adj.append (mygraph.get (u))
        for v in adj:
            if v not in level:
                level [v] = i
                parent [v] = u
                nex.extend (v)
    frontier = nex
    i += 1
```

Comment: Use tuples instead of lists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371358/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)

Comment: looks like you want to be calling `adj.extend` not `adj.append` though I cannot be sure without more information

Comment: @jonrsharpe I substituted adj with a tuple but I don't know how to append new items to a tuple?

Comment: ...you can't add new items to a tuple, they're immutable, which is why you can use them as keys. If you had a mutable key, how could you be sure you were getting the right value back out of the dictionary?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah, that's the case, but I cannot solve it because my keys while are unique, need to be updated in each iteration!

Answer (score 0):

Currently `v` is a list of vertices, not a single vertex. This causes errors when you try to use it as a dictionary key. Using it that way is a bug. Your dictionaries are supposed to be mapping from single vertexes, like `"1"` to other things, but you're using the wrong values as keys when you get your `v` values from the `adj` list.

I don't think you need to maintain an `adj` list at all. You just want to loop once over the members of the adjacency list of `u` once, then get a new list of adjacent vertices for the next vertex in your `frontier`.

So, rather than:

```
adj.append (mygraph.get (u))
for v in adj:
```

Just do:

```
for v in mygraph.get(u):
```

(And throw away the `adj` variable that you no longer need.)

Note that if your graph is not complete, that is, there are some vertices that have no out-edges, you may want to change the `get` call to `mygraph.get(u, [])` so that it always returns something iterable.

Comment: good comments, I did so and the error went away but now I am facing this error "'NoneType' object is not iterable", any idea?

Comment: I suspect you're hitting the issue my last paragraph is talking about. At some point you're looking up a vertex that doesn't exist as a key in your graph, and `dict.get` returns `None` by default when you request such a key. You can probably fix it bypassing in some empty iterable object as the second argument to `get`.