# python 2-D list how to make a set

Tags: python

as a python list follow

```
list1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[1,2]]
```

I want make a set so I can the unique list items like

```
list2 = [[1,2],[3,4]].
```

Is there some function in python I can use. Thanks

Comment: list() are mutable type and cannot be added to a set. You need to convert them to a tuple and then add them to a set().

Comment: What is the usecase? Will you update the lists?

Comment: Funny that this question got more answers than the so called dupicate - in just one hour.  What was the point to marking this as a duplicate?  Just to keep people from proposing more ideas?

Answer (score 3):

That will do:

```
>>> list1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[1,2]]
>>> list2 = list(map(list, set(map(tuple,list1))))
>>> list2
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Nice one-liner. Better than my answer!

Comment: Why the last list()? map([list, set(map(tuple, a))) seems to work fine.

Comment: @NickM. `map` returns an iterator (in python 3)

Comment: @NickM. for clarity: `map` returns an iterator in Python 3, but a `list` in Python 2.

Comment: Thanks,I get it,you answer is very clear

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not a single built-in function that can handle this. Lists are "unhashable" (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371358/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)). So you cannot have a `set` of `list` in Python.

But tuples *are* hashable:

```
l = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2]]
s = {tuple(x) for x in l}

print(s)

# out: {(1, 2), (3, 4)}
```

Of course, this won't help you if you want to later, say, `append` to these lists inside your main data structure, as they are now all tuples. If you absolutely **must** have the original list functionality, you can check out [this code recipe for uniquification by Tim Peters](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52560/).

Answer (score 1):

Note that this only removes duplicate sublists, it does not take into account the sublist's individual elements. Ex: `[[1,2,3], [1,2], [1]]` -> `[[1,2,3], [1,2], [1]]`

```
>>> print map(list, {tuple(sublist) for sublist in list1})
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
list1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[1,2]]
list2 = []
for i in list1:
    if i not in list2:
        list2.append(i)
print(list2)
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: This would perform poorly for large lists with many unique items, right? I'm not sure what the precise algorithmic complexity would be, but it approaches O(n^2) as the number of unique items approaches n, I think.

Comment: @PierceDarragh You can always test performance. I checked it against your solution and my answer is faster.

Answer (score 0):

The most typical solutions have already been posted, so let's give a new one:

**Python 2.x**

```
list1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2]]
list2 = {str(v): v for v in list1}.values()
```

**Python 3.x**

```
list1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2]]
list2 = list({str(v): v for v in list1}.values())
```

Comment: Side note: `values()` will not give a list in Python 3, but a `dict_values` object

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I know but OP didn't specify which python version he was using (python tag), so this is a perfectly valid answer ;-) . Anyway, let me edit

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt single function to achieve this. You have received many answers. In addition to those, you may also use a `lambda` function to achieve this:

```
list(map(list, set(map(lambda i: tuple(i), list1))))
```

Comment: As a warning: please don't use comments to ask people to vote for your answer. We just deleted over 50 of these, and they are nothing but noise.