# python 2-D array get the function as np.unique or union1d

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

as follows I have a 2-D list/array

```
list1 = [[1,2],[3,4]]
list2 = [[3,4],[5,6]]
```

how can I use the function as `union1d(x,y)`to make list1 and list2 as one list

```
list3 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

Comment: The answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array address both the simple case (where “unique” sub-lists means “bit-exact”) and the floating-point case (where you want to treat two sub-lists as “equal” if they’re within some tolerance of each other). Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Ahmed Fasih ths,and to get the unique 2-D list,the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39081807/python-2-d-list-how-to-make-a-set) has solved my unique problem,this problem I main want find a function that can merge two lists samply

Comment: For small lists, the Python list methods in your other SO question are gong to be faster than these `numpy` ones.   It takes time to convert a list into an array.

Comment: A list version based on the other SO question: `[list(x) for x in {tuple(x) for x in list1+list2}]`

Answer (score 1):

`union1d` just does:

```
unique(np.concatenate((ar1, ar2)))
```

so if you have a method of finding unique rows, you have the solution.

As described in the suggested link, and elsewhere, you can do this by converting the array to a 1d structured array.  Here the simple version is

If `arr` is:

```
arr=np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[3,4],[5,6]])
```

the structured equivalent (a view, same data):

```
In [4]: arr.view('i,i')
Out[4]: 
array([[(1, 2)],
       [(3, 4)],
       [(3, 4)],
       [(5, 6)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])

In [5]: np.unique(arr.view('i,i'))
Out[5]: 
array([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

and back to 2d int:

```
In [7]: np.unique(arr.view('i,i')).view('2int')
Out[7]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

This solution does require a certain familiarity with compound dtypes.

Using `return_index` saves that return view.  We can index `arr` directly with that index:

```
In [54]: idx=np.unique(arr.view('i,i'),return_index=True)[1]

In [55]: arr[idx,:]
Out[55]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

For what it's worth, `unique` does a `sort` and then uses a mask approach to remove adjacent duplicates.

It's the `sort` that requires a 1d array, the rest works in 2d

Here `arr` is already sorted

```
In [42]: flag=np.concatenate([[True],(arr[1:,:]!=arr[:-1,:]).all(axis=1)])

In [43]: flag
Out[43]: array([ True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [44]: arr[flag,:]
Out[44]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16971324/901925 shows this working with `lexsort`.

================

The mention of `np.union1d` set me and Divakar to focus on numpy methods.  But it starting with lists (of lists), it is likely to be faster to use Python set methods.

For example, using list and set comprehensions:

```
In [99]: [list(x) for x in {tuple(x) for x in list1+list2}]
Out[99]: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

You could also take the set for each list, and do a set `union`.

The `tuple` conversion is needed because a list isn't hashable.

Comment: All your examples use `unique`, not `union1d`. Is this deliberate?

Comment: Just easier to deal with one array after concatenation. `union1d` starts with a concatenation.  Divakar tries to make the case for performing the union without first concatenating.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to stack those two input arrays vertically with `np.vstack` and then finding the unique rows in it. It would be memory intensive as we would discard rows from it thereafter.

Another approach would be to find the rows in the first array that are exclusive to it, i.e. not present in the second array and thus just stacking those exclusive rows alongwith the second array. Of course, this would assume that there are unique rows among each input array.

The crux of such a proposed memory-saving implementation would be to get those exclusive rows from first array. For the same we would convert each row into a linear index equivalent considering each row as an indexing tuple on a n-dimensional grid, with the `n` being the number of columns in the input arrays. Thus, assuming the input arrays as `arr1` and `arr2`, we would have an implementation like so -

```
# Get dim of ndim-grid on which linear index equivalents are to be mapped
dims = np.maximum(arr1.max(0),arr2.max(0)) + 1

# Get linear index equivalents for arr1, arr2
idx1 = np.ravel_multi_index(arr1.T,dims)
idx2 = np.ravel_multi_index(arr2.T,dims)

# Finally get the exclusive rows and stack with arr2 for desired o/p
out = np.vstack((arr1[~np.in1d(idx1,idx2)],arr2))
```

Sample run -

```
In [93]: arr1
Out[93]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 3]])

In [94]: arr2
Out[94]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [5, 6]])

In [95]: out
Out[95]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

For more info on setting up those linear index equivalents, please refer to [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38674038/3293881).

Comment: `in1d` does `unique` on the 2 inputs separately, and then a `unique` like  operation on their concatenation.

Comment: @hpaulj Good to know! Shouldn't do `return_index` though.