# Pandas groupby over list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame in the following format:

```
Arrival Departure Park Station Count 
      8        10    5   [1,2]     1
      5        12    6   [3,4]     1
      8        10    5   [1,2]     1
```

I want to groupby this data frame by arrival, departure, park and station but since station is a list, I am getting an error. The output should look like:

```
    Arrival Departure Park Station Count 
        8        10    5   [1,2]     2
        5        12    6   [3,4]     1
```

Could you please let me know if there is any way to solve this issue?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I want to get a data frame by grouping the rows based on arrival, departure,park and station.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that a [Python `list` is a mutable type, and hence unhashable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371358/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-list). In the place you'd put in the `groupby` criterion `df.Station`, put instead `df.Station.apply(tuple)`. This will transform the lists into tuples, which are hashable (and immutable).

For example:

```
In [66]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Arrival': [8, 5, 4], 'Station': [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2]]})

In [67]: df.groupby([df.Arrival, df.Station.apply(tuple)]).Arrival.sum()
Out[67]: 
Arrival  Station
4        (1, 2)     4
5        (3, 4)     5
8        (1, 2)     8
Name: Arrival, dtype: int64
```

Conversely,

```
df.groupby([df.Arrival, df.Station]).Arrival.sum()
```

won't work.

Comment: It works but it gives me Series. How can I make it a dataframe?

Comment: @user36729 Whenever you have a series `s`, and wish to make it into a DataFrame, you can use `s.to_frame()`.

Comment: Thanks. In this way, both 'Arrival' and 'Station' stick together in the index of data frame. Is there anyway to split them?

Comment: @user36729 Happy to answer, but these questions have less to do with your original problem, and more to do with general `groupby` stuff. It's a bit hard to do a dialog in the comments. Nevertheless, after `.to_frame()`, you can call `.reset_index()`. If it complains about existing columns, use in between `.rename(columns={'Arrival': 'count})` (or whatever columns you have).

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'arrival':[8,5,8], 'departure':[10,12,10], \
'park':[5,6,5], 'station':[[1,2], [3,4], [1,2]]})

df['arrival_station'] = df.station.apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['departure_station'] = df.station.apply(lambda x: x[1])
print df

   arrival  departure  park station  arrival_station  departure_station
0        8         10     5  [1, 2]                1                  2
1        5         12     6  [3, 4]                3                  4
2        8         10     5  [1, 2]                1                  2
```

Now your station data is free and you can groupby as normal.