# why does my tk tabbed for loop have an error of "tabs[upper_tabs] = self.tab TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, tkinter, tabs, ttk

I can create the 2 tabs individually, and I am trying to make it expendable by using a for loop.  I get an error that says

```
tabs[upper_tabs] = self.tab
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I am assuming it's how I reference the dictionary.  Would you please help me understand and correct the error.

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk

upper_tabs = ["Final", "Requests"]
tabs = {}

class Application(ttk.Frame): #inherent from frame.
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="ivory2")
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack()

    self.tabControl = ttk.Notebook(self, width="900", height= "350") # 
       Create Tab Control

    for names in upper_tabs:
        self.tab=ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)# Create a tab
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab, text=names)      # Add the tab
        tabs[names] = self.tab
        self.tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")  # Pack to make visible
        self.grid()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("class basic window")
    root.geometry("1200x600")
    root.config(background="LightBlue4")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: [Because you're indexing a dict with a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371358/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-list).

Comment: Now try to figure out what is a dict and what is a list yourself and what you want to do instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you want to do, but to remove the error and make the program look like this...
[image]
(Scaled down) 
... is to change the line `tabs[upper_tabs] = self.tab` to `tabs[tuple(upper_tabs)] = self.tab`.

This works because a `tuple` *cannot change*, and it is, therefore, possible to use it as a dictionary key, which a `list` can't be. For more on python dictionaries, see [this page](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/).

Comment: @user202729   thank you for your time.  It's a good thing you point out the list and the tuple for key knowledge.  I didn't know that and took some time to read it.  I figured out exactly what I wanted and updated the code.  in the code is what i want.  tabs side by side through a for loop.  thanks again.