# Shows a TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python

This is a K-Knights problem solved with CSP, and the issue seems to be the constraints.

Error coming from here

File "F:/Lectures/AI Lab/Codes/nonattacking/aicodes/csp.py", line 23, in **init**
    self.setUpVariableDomains()

File "F:/Lectures/AI Lab/Codes/nonattacking/aicodes/csp.py", line 28, in setUpVariableDomains
    self.addVariableDomain(var, self._domain)

File "F:/Lectures/AI Lab/Codes/nonattacking/aicodes/csp.py", line 35, in addVariableDomain
    self._domainOfVariable[var] = copy.deepcopy(domain)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

```
import variable
import copy
import notEqualConstraint
import simpleInference
import time
import backtrackingSearch
import consoleListener
import nonAttackingConstraint
class CSP():

def __init__(self, variables = [], domains = [], constraints = []):
    self._variables = variables
    self._domain = domains
    self._constraints = constraints
    self._domainOfVariable = {}
    self._contraintsOfVariable = {}
    self.setUpVariableDomains()
    self.setUpConstraints()

def setUpVariableDomains(self):
    for var in self._variables:
        self.addVariableDomain(var, self._domain)

def setUpConstraints(self):
    for constraint in self._constraints:
        self.addConstraint(constraint)

def addVariableDomain(self,var,domain):
    self._domainOfVariable[var] = copy.deepcopy(domain)

def addConstraint(self,constraint):
    for var in constraint.getScope():
        if var not in self._contraintsOfVariable:
            self._contraintsOfVariable[var] = []
            self._contraintsOfVariable[var].append(constraint)

def addSingleConstraint(self,constraint):
    self._constraints.append(constraint)
    for var in constraint.getScope():
        if var not in self._contraintsOfVariable:
            self._contraintsOfVariable[var] = []
            self._contraintsOfVariable[var].append(constraint)

def addVariable(self,variable):
    self._variables.append(variable)
    self.addVariableDomain(variable,self._domain)

def getVariables(self):
    return self._variables

def getDomainValues(self,var):
    return self._domainOfVariable[var]

def getConstraints(self,var):
    if var not in self._contraintsOfVariable:
        return []
    return self._contraintsOfVariable[var]

def getVariableDomains(self):
    return self._domainOfVariable

def setVariableDomains(self,domainOfVariable):
    self._domainOfVariable = domainOfVariable

def copy(self):
    variables = copy.deepcopy(self._variables)
    domains = copy.deepcopy(self._variables)
    constraints = copy.deepcopy(self._variables)
    csp = CSP(variables, domains, constraints)
    return csp

def getNeighbour(self,variable,constraint):
    neigh = []
    for va in constraint.getScope():
        if va != variable and (va not in neigh):
            neigh.append(va)
            return neigh

def removeValueFromDomain(self,variable,value):
    values = []
    for val in self.getDomainValues(variable):
        if val != value:
            values.append(val)
            self._domainOfVariable[variable] = values


if __name__ == '__main__':

    domains = ["K","A"]


    variables = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

    X=[[2,1],[2,-1],[-2,1],[-2,-1],[1,2],[1,-2],[-1,2],[-1,-2]]

    constraints = [
    nonAttackingConstraint.NotAttackingConstraint(X)



        ]


    Csp = CSP(variables,domains,constraints)
    inPro = simpleInference.SimpleInference()
    bts = backtrackingSearch.BactrackingSearch(inPro,[consoleListener.ConsoleListener()],variableOrdering = True)
    start = time.time()
    result = bts.solve(Csp)
    end = time.time()
    print("%.2f ‐ %.2f" % (start,end))
```

Specifically stops at addVariableDomain in the CSP Class above, and gives me the unhashable type: 'list' error due to my constraint being a list. Is the issue identifiable? Is there a solution?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371358/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)! It might be because you are using `{}`.

Comment: Shows this when I change it to ()


TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Answer (score 0):

Lists can not be used as dictionary keys as they are mutable and hence not suitable for hashing. Try converting the list to tuple.

```
def addVariableDomain(self,var,domain):
    self._domainOfVariable[tuple(var)] = copy.deepcopy(domain)
```

You may have to do the same wherever `var` is used as a dictionary key.

Comment: Yes thank you that seems to have worked, though it gave me another error right after for a similar thing


  File "F:/Lectures/AI Lab/Codes/nonattacking/aicodes/csp.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.setUpConstraints()


  File "F:/Lectures/AI Lab/Codes/nonattacking/aicodes/csp.py", line 32, in setUpConstraints
    self.addConstraint(constraint)


  File "F:/Lectures/AI Lab/Codes/nonattacking/aicodes/csp.py", line 39, in addConstraint
    if var not in self._contraintsOfVariable:


TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: See my last line in the answer. You will have to convert `var` to `tuple(var)` wherever you are using `var` as a dictionary key such as `self._contraintsOfVariable[var]`, etc.