# unhashable type: 'list' in making a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to write a program that creates a dictionary whose keys are the numbers and whose values are the how many times the number occurs but I am getting this message:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   
>   File "C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/v7.py", line 8, in <module>   
>     if r in d:        
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
> ```

```
from random import randint
d={}
grid = [[randint(1, 5)for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)]

print(grid)

for r in grid:
    if r in d:
        d[r]=d[r]+1
    else:
        d[r]=1
```

Comment: `r` is not defined in this code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371358/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)

Comment: Your error couldn't be more clear: When you check `if r in d`, keys inside dictionaries need to be hashable, and `i` is a list of 5 random numbers that you generated within each item of `grid`. You can clean this up by checking the linked question. Changing `[randint(1, 5)for j in range(5)]` into a tuple will solve this, unless you meant to check a list of lists, then Vasco's answer is more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using your variable grid as it was a list, but it is a list of lists. You should iterate twice (you are only iterating one - over the lists)

The following code should work:

```
from random import randint
d={}
grid = [[randint(1, 5)for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)]

print(grid)

for array in grid: # iterate over every list inside the list of lists
    for element in array: # iterate over every element inside a list
        if element in d: # check if element is a key in d
            d[element]=d[element]+1 
        else:
            d[element]=1
```

## EDIT: By sugestion of [scott-hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535275/scott-hunter), I include the code with defaultdicts:

In defaultdicts, you initially state the default value of a key

```
from random import randint
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
grid = [[randint(1, 5)for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)]

print(grid)

for array in grid:
    for element in array:
        d[element]=d[element]+1
```

Comment: Using a `defaultdict` would make this even cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

`i` is a `list`, which is not hashable, and dictionary keys have to be hashable.

Since you claim to be looking for numbers, you probably meant to test each *element* of `i` and not the whole list.