# How to fix this error "unhashable type: 'list"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, dictionary

In a sample in CSV file below, I am looking to get all times which each user takes on each screen through taken into considerations three independent variables which are "IpAddress","timeStamp" and "screenName". I got the error " unhashable type: 'list'".

```py
fn3 = 'screenviewclean.1.csv'
f2 = open(fn3,"r")
filereader = csv.reader(f2)
mhist = {}
i = 0

for line in filereader:
    i+=1   
    sec= line [10]
    IpAddress = line [2]
    timeStamp = line [6]
    time = timeStamp[11:13]+ timeStamp[13:19]
    Screen_View = line [7]
    if i>1:
        if IpAddress in mhist.keys():
            mhist[IpAddress].append(Screen_View)
        else:
            mhist[IpAddress] = [Screen_View] 
    
#print (mhist)

chist = {}

for ip, screen in mhist.items():
    k = screen
    #print (k)
    if k in chist.keys():
        chist[k].append (time)
    else:
        chist[k] = [time]

print (chist)
```

This a sample of the csv file which I have:

```
Unnamed: 0  lastLoggedVersion   IpAddress   deviceId    deviceOS    userId  timeStamp   screenName  userType    doc.id  seconds
0   1.6.0.1 192.168.0.77    7612F62D-E392-4269-B49B-4F1214AA3888    iOS13.6.1   5U1XW8wkoqUPCTGhC1ni9Whinvt1    2020-11-13 22:28:55.029000+00:00    StudentProfile  student 00mrvPyS9Y2Al9iTN1vw    1231534.547
2   1.6.1.44    10.0.2.16   40a4dc7cb837fdec    Android10   27lFw6EnfbYFsU3F8AEejYGQRRl1    2020-11-12 21:28:00.998000+00:00    CompanySettings company 01dMOvAgsRTPSWXTDXIh    1141480.516
6   1.6.0.43    192.168.87.241  ec62706b2834bfcc    Android9    7XBtY5ZDxcPWYF7sGECDZxnH71b2    2020-11-12 21:41:33.126000+00:00    DiscoverCompanies   student 064kDvawK8cJoRl5if9d    1142292.644
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371358/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)

Comment: Convert your list to a tuple. Lists cannot be used as dict keys.

Comment: Dict keys need to be immutable. If you change the list after putting it in the dict then it will have a different hash value and won't be retrievable anymore. To avoid this kind of subtle bugs this error is thrown.

Comment: This is not answer my question. I am looking to get all times which for each user takes to watch each screen. This means I have to make a link between three variables in this dataset which are  "IpAddress","timeStamp" and "screenName".This problem in my code that I get a list for each ip address in a dictionary of lists. I am looking to get a the ip address for each screen in mhist1 dictionary. something like that {'IP1': 'screen1', 'IP1': 'screen2', 'IP2': 'screen1', 'IP2': 'screen2'

Comment: I tried to change the code for mhist1 to: if IpAddress in mhist.keys():
            mhist[IpAddress] = Screen_View
        else:
            mhist[IpAddress] = Screen_View

Comment: What is IpAddress?

Comment: But this doesn't work as well because it gives me the last screen watched for each ip address only

Comment: This is an exmaple of IP-Address (IpAddress
192.168.0.77
10.0.2.16
192.168.87.241
192.168.1.8
0.0.0.0
)

Comment: each user has a unique IpAdress so to get all times that  each user takes for watching each screen so I have to use the IpAddress to identify the user

Comment: It has nothing to do with your question, but your code would be simpler if you made `chist` and `mhist` into `collections.defaultdict(list)`.  You could then just use `append` without checking if the key is already present.  An empty list will automatically be created.

Comment: Could you please give me a simple example about your idea?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including the full error message with traceback. I tried running your code but got a different error, `IndexError: list index out of range` at `sec = line[10]`.

Answer (score 1):

You have `for ip, screen in mhist.items()`.  But the values in that dictionary are a list of screens, not a single screen.

You need

```
for ip, screens in mhist.items():
    for screen in screens:
       ....
```

Comment: I got the same many repeated values for each Ip-Address:

Comment: {'StudentProfile': ['21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40', '21:22:40'

Comment: That what I did: for ip, screens in mhist.items():
    for screen in screens:
        k = screen
        #print (k)
        if k in chist.keys():
            chist[k].append (time)
        else:
            chist[k] = [time]
            
print (chist)

Comment: On top of everything use, you're using csv.read(), but your data appears to have no commas in it.